# Null values from form to managedbeans

Tags: java, jsf, web-applications

I'm doing my first JSF application and I'm implementing the login page. But I'm having problems when I'll submit the form with login and password. I use JSF 2.0

I have the following form:

```
<h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:outputLabel for="txt_login" value="Login" />
                <p:inputText id="txt_login" value="#{loginBean.login}"/>
                <p:outputLabel for="txt_senha" value="Senha" />
                <p:inputText id="txt_senha" value="#{loginBean.senha}"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginBean.efetuaLogin}" />
                <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" action="cancelar" />
            </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

And the ManagedBean:

```
@ManagedBean
public class LoginBean {

private String login;
private String senha;

public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}

public void setSenha(String senha) {
    System.out.println("SENHA = " + this.getSenha());
    this.senha = senha;
}

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public void setLogin(String login) {
    System.out.println("USER = " + this.getLogin());
    this.login = login;
}

public String efetuaLogin() {
    Usuario user = new Usuario(this.login, this.senha);
    System.out.println("USER = " + this.getLogin() + " SENHA = " + this.getSenha());
    UsuarioController.getInstance().save(user);
    return "sucesso";

}

public String cadastar() {
    Usuario user = new Usuario(this.login, this.senha);
    System.out.println("USER = " + this.login + " SENHA = " + this.senha);
    UsuarioController.getInstance().save(user);
    return "sucesso";
}

}
```

When these form is submitted is passed null for my managed bean. Why it happens?

Comment: As your facelet code, as well as your bean code is valid (though sometimes strange), you should look for the problem in your configuration. Show is your web.xml and faces-config.xml, if you have the latter.

Comment: I changed the <p:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginBean.efetuaLogin}" /> by <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginBean.efetuaLogin}" /> and now the fields are being setted. But I do not understand why primefaces component does not works

Answer (score 0):

Add a scope for ManagedBean, For login add `@RequestScoped`. You used `<h:inputText` for password. Please use `<h:inputSecret/>` for password.

Comment: I added @RequestScoped but did not solve the problem. :(
Is necessary map the managedbean on faces-config.xml or using the annotation is enough?
And I'll change for <h:inputSecret/>, it's just a test. ;)

Comment: xml is alternate of Annotaion. Annotation is enough.

Comment: What is the namespace of <p: tag? Is it from primeface?

Comment: You shouldn't post comments as answers. Your comment, though has remarks on how to structure the code in a more 'mainstream' manner, doesn't answer the question at all. And it is not that xml configuration is alternative to annotation-driven configuration, the former takes strict precedence over the latter and the latter, if I recall JSF specs correctly, is in its turn ultimately translated into xml.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `System.out.println` too early hence you think you're getting `null` but you're not. Example:

```
public void setSenha(String senha) {
    System.out.println("SENHA = " + this.getSenha());
    this.senha = senha;
}
```

should be

```
public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
    System.out.println("SENHA = " + this.getSenha());
}
```

Same thing with `setLogin(String login)`

**UPDATE #2** 
Your problem must be somewhere else. Check to see if you are using the correct namespace for primefaces

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui
```

As far as I can tell, all primefaces components are working for me. As an example here is my code. Try to run it against the original `.xhtml` that you posted. The only difference is the edits I told you above and my `LoginBean` does not have `UsuarioController.getInstance().save(user);`

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class LoginBean {

    private String login;
    private String senha;

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
        System.out.println("SENHA = " + this.getSenha());

    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
        System.out.println("USER = " + this.getLogin());
    }

    public String efetuaLogin() {
        User user = new User(this.login, this.senha);
        System.out.println("USER = " + this.getLogin() + " SENHA = " + this.getSenha());
        System.out.println("ACTUAL USER = " + user.getLogin() + " ACTUAL SENHA = " + user.getSenha());
        return "sucesso";
    }

    public String cadastar() {
        return "sucesso";
    }
}


public class User {
    private String login; 
    private String senha; 

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public User(String login, String senha) {
        this.login = login;
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public User() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeap... I saw this noob code after some time, I put other sysout efetuaLogin() method. But I also saw that primefaces component does not works correncly. I changed the <p:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginBean.efetuaLogin}" /> by <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginBean.efetuaLogin}" /> and now the fields are being setted. But I do not understand why primefaces component does not works

Comment: I did what you suggested for me... and the console output put was:
USER = 
SENHA = 
USER =  SENHA = 
ACTUAL USER =  ACTUAL SENHA =

Comment: Did you try adding values in the input boxes before hitting login (stupid question I know but indulge me) ? What version of primefaces are you using ? Can you post the entire code of your the xhtml and both classes ? the entire thing with import statements. I don't need the controller.

Comment: Also, is this a Maven project ? Are you sure you have all the jar files ?

Comment: No, it's not a maven project. Sure, if I did not have all jar files the others primefaces would not working, like commandButton

Comment: Yep you are right. It's just that the other day I was helping someone and we had the same issue (working on my end and not working on his)

Comment: Ok, no problems. I understand you, everyone has had this problem ;)

Comment: @vanz Are you posting it or did you give up ?

Comment: No no... I'm looking for a resolution.

Comment: @vanz If you are indeed new to JSF, I would suggest you stick with it and forget primefaces for now. I'm not trying to discourage you but try to know the basics first before trying to fly ;)